# Calendar Report in Cognos 10 Report Studio

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

How to create calendar type report in "cognos" report studio with separate month wise display and also with weekend and holidays highlighted???????????

I already created a report which displays calendar layout, but i'm not able to implement holiday logic in it

Note:I used repeater table and cross tab to display calander

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to highlighting for weekends.

1. Create boolean style variable with formula:

   _day_of_week ( [Your_date_field], 1 ) in (6,7)
2. Apply this style variable to cell (for example)
3. Set up highlighting for TRUE value.

But for there is no built-in holidays. You need to create (and maintain) your own calendar table in database.

Comment: Thanks for this,I already highlighted weekend and tried many ways to highlight holidays and yet to get successed